# axslx: undefined method for yard

Tags: yard, axlsx

I'm running "yard server -g" but it's only generating the Table of Contents for axlsx.

When I click on a class I get:

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass.
```

Any idea why? 
(Fwiw, other gems are working fine in Yard server)

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem, then noticed in console: "[error]: Missing 'kramdown' gem for Markdown formatting. Install it with `gem install kramdown`"

I installed kramdown, and lo and behold! It worked.

Comment: This works. Added to the bug report on the gem https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/311

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, the last release has a .yardoc folder with incomplete documentation.

Here is a workaround you can use until I release an updated version of the gem.

- use the following command to locate the installed gem:

`gem which axlsx`

- navigate to the gem top directory and:

`rm -rf .yardoc`

- restart your yard server, and it will rebuild the current release documents.

`yard server -g`

Again, sincerest apologies for the pain.

best

randym

Comment: This didn't work for me. I went to ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/axlsx-1.3.6, deleted .yardoc, restarted my yard server but had the same problem.